# .NET Convert bitmap frames from Web Cam to byte array using ArrayPool

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, directshow.net

I am writing ASP .NET app where you can watch video from Web Cam. I am using AForge.Video.DirectShow namespace to connect to Web Cam. It returns me the frames as bitmaps but I need it to pass along as byte arrays. I tried to do this with ArrayPool and also use RecyclableMemoryStreamManager for recycling the memory streams. Here is a class (simplified to include only relevant parts) I wrote for this.

```
public class WebCamWrapper
{
    private readonly VideoCaptureDevice videoSource;
    private const int DefaultArraySize = 5000000;
    private readonly ArrayPool<byte> byteArrayPool;
    private readonly RecyclableMemoryStreamManager memoryStreamManager;

    public byte[] FrameBytes { get; set; }

    public WebCamWrapper()
    {
        byteArrayPool = ArrayPool<byte>.Create();
        memoryStreamManager = new RecyclableMemoryStreamManager();
        FilterInfoCollection videoDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
        videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice(videoDevices[0].MonikerString);
        videoSource.NewFrame += OnNewFrameReceived;
    }

    private void OnNewFrameReceived(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs frameEventArgs)
    {
        byte[] buffer = byteArrayPool.Rent(DefaultArraySize);
        try
        {
            ConvertToArray((Bitmap)frameEventArgs.Frame.Clone(), buffer);
        }
        finally
        {
            byteArrayPool.Return(buffer);
        }
    }

    private void ConvertToArray(Bitmap frame, byte[] buffer)
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = memoryStreamManager.GetStream("ConvertToArray", buffer, 0, buffer.Length))
        {
            frame.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
            FrameBytes = stream.GetBuffer();
        }
    }
}
```

Then I will call the FrameBytes property from different class in a loop (polling basically). This works I was just wondering if there is a better way(in performance) and also I am not sure I am using the ArrayPool correctly here.

P.S. Right now I would want to optimize this conversion from Bitmap to byte array and not to look at the architecture of the app. However, if you have some suggestion how to do this in completely different I will also appreciate it (who knows how the app will look in the future)

Comment: What is the current performance then? And what do you want it to be? Are you talking memory performance or CPU ticks performance or something else?

Comment: What I had in mind was 1) memory performance (this seemed to get better using array pool and recycling memory streams) 2) reduce delay between camera and showed image ( right now approx. 2-3 seconds running on localhost)